# rewriting urls in wordpress .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

Im new to wordpress and to server admin in general,
 I just installed a wordpress blog in a sub-folder of my local directory. But I have a problem configuring the .htaccess. The folder where the wordpress is installed is called onlifestyle and is in the root directory. 
My urls have the form:
http://onlifestyle.org/onlifestyle/health/basic-principles-of-proper-nutrition
instead 
http://onlifestyle.org/health/basic-principles-of-proper-nutrition
my root .htaccess is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?onlifestyle.org$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ onlifestyle/$1 [NC,L]
```

the wordpress .htaccess:

```
 # BEGIN WordPress
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule . /onlifestyle/index.php [L]
    </IfModule>
#END WordPress
```

and Im using permalinks:

```
http://onlifestyle.org/onlifestyle/%category%/%postname%
```

how should I configure wordpress in-order to skip the name of the sub-directory in the urls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aparat from .htaccess file, you must set proper URL in Wordpress settings. See also: http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory